# Is there any way to revert playstore update?

Tags: flutter

I created a new release.aab file and uploaded the bundle to playstore. It is still in review. But I found that I missed a crucial step in payment method. Is there any way to revert or delete the release? I am using flutter for development. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

there is not any way to delete a release or stop it when it is in progress mode but as you know at google play console we have multiple streams to release our app like open testing, close testing, internal testing, and production so if your release lies in any of these once Google play team approved it they ask you to roll out that version at that point you can stop this release or I can say discard that release and upload a new updated one. I hope that my answer will help you out

Answer (score 0):

Google Play store does not allow to remove releases, you can only go forward.
My suggestion is to just create a new release overriding the one you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to delete a release, but there is a way to prevent it from being published automatically. Go to the developer page and go to Publication overview (sidebar, left side) and enable managed publications and check Managed Publishing Enabled (right side of the screen). So your application, even after the analysis, will not be published automatically, which gives you time to generate another version, upload it and after analysis it will replace the current one, in this format you must access the Publication overview and accept the publication of your application manually.